# How to read a file in a shared Xamarin project?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using MvvmCross for my Xamarin application, so I have 3 projects: `MyProject.Core`, `MyProject.Droid` and `MyProject.Touch`

I have `file.txt` in the `MyProject.Core` project. I want to be able to open and read `file.txt` from my code in `MyProject.Core` so that it can be used on both platforms. It sounds simple but I can't figure out how. I found 2 approaches but I don't think they can work for me:

1) I make `file.txt` an embedded resource and read it at runtime via reflection. But I don't think I can do this in a PCL.

2) I set `file.txt` to "Copy to output directory", but this won't work either because the resulting package (.ipa or .apk) won't have access to it once it's on the phone (right?)

**EDIT**

I just thought of a solution that will suffice to my situation:

1. Add `file.txt` to `MyProject.Core`
2. In the iOS project, add the same file as a LINK in the `Resources` folder.
3. In the Android project, add the same file as a LINK in the `values` folder.

Although I still can not access `file.txt` from `MyProject.Core`, I can access the same file from each platform, which is a sufficient solution to my situation. I'll leave the question here in case anyone has an answer to this specific scenario for someone else that needs it.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/#Loading_and_Saving_Files

Comment: That section explains how to read/write files from the user. I'm asking how to read a file that I (the developer) placed myself in the shared project. But I think there is no way and that my alternative solution is the only way...

Comment: Does not matter if you are talking about an end user or your code, reading a file, is reading a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the type of your Core project is a NET Standard project you can just use the standard System.IO classes to get hold of the file system.

If it is a PCL (you probably want to upgrade it) you can use the MvvmCross File plugin to access the file system or the PCLStorage nuget. Whichever you prefer.

Using the former you would add the MvvmCross.Plugins.File nuget to core, and both app projects. Then you can add `IMvxFileStore` in the ctor of the ViewModel or Service you want to inject it. Then start using any of the methods on that interface to operate on the file system.

However, for embedded resources in your PCL you could do something like:

```cs
var assembly = typeof(SomeTypeInYourPCL).Assembly;
// some older PCL profiles you need to call .GetTypeInfo() before .Assembly
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("whatever.txt");
```